# Eclipse with C++ compiler bundle

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction

I'm about to teach intro C++ class and would like to use Eclipse for the development/learning. In order for students to setup Eclipse C++ to work on Windows it will not be very intuitive to install the compiler then install Eclipse and configure it. My question, is there a way to bundle them together and then provide students with those files to extract on their computer and start development.

Comment: Just write a batch file that does all the work. Voting to move to superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/) to the default install location `C:\MinGW` then the [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) will automatically detect the MinGW toolchain and configure itself correctly.

If you run into issues make sure the PATH variable points to `C:\MinGW\bin`, this can be done automatically by providing a script to your students but may not be neccecary as the MinGW installer should do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Are all of your students working on the same computers such as lab computers? Or on their own computers, which may have different os and 64/32 bit?

If they are all working on the same platform you could create a directory with applicable java/eclipse/and c compilers and a quick tutorial with a script to set their environment variables.

If they are working on their own computers this becomes very complicated. They will need different versions of each java/eclipse/ c compiler and will probably each run into different issues.

I am a student and we tend to have old computers. The first time I tried to run eclipse cdt was on a computer with vista.

That being said, you can create a zip directory with several different options that they could download and install. This is a headache I had to do for my senior design team. 7 of us ran into 6 different issues.